# Is there a seperate something in front logarithm that is raising a base to a power?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I am trying to solve a problem with the following form

$$e^{\displaystyle A\log(x)}$$

$e^{\log(x)}$ is simply $x$, but how do I go about separating the $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the rules for logarithms to move the $A$. In particular, the rule you want is $A\log x = \log(x^A)$.

Comment: So is it just x^a?

Comment: Yes it is just $x^A$.

Comment: You can also (not coincidentally) use the laws of exponentials to do this; namely, $e^{ab}=(e^a)^b$. So, you can write $e^{A\log x}=(e^{\log x})^A=x^A$.